# How fix the render problem faced in android studio

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing a render problem in android studio 3.5 and I am not able to see anything on the design view
Here is the link to the image (https://imagebin.ca/v/4u6FFIcRScdm)

I have already tried clean code from build options and replaced the   styles.xml Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar with Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Here is the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Cleaner
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation_Original(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:130)
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.java:66)
    at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:119)
    at android.os.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:404)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub.<init>(IInputMethodClient.java:18)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1.<init>(InputMethodManager.java:606)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.<init>(InputMethodManager.java:606)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager_Delegate.getInstance(InputMethodManager_Delegate.java:43)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.getInstance(InputMethodManager.java:681)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.setUp(RenderAction.java:249)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.init(RenderAction.java:137)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:164)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:392)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:200)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:572)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:698)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1771)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Comment: Include the layout XML file in your question as well.

Comment: Add your activity_main.xml in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was trying to activate BarcodeScanner on Emulator, which is not possible as Emulator does not have it and it was throwing NoClassDefFoundError. I used try...catch... to solve this issue while running app on Emulator. Once I installed it on real device it was not throwing this error for obvious. You can use it like this,

```
 try {

     //Code that is throwing this error

 } catch (NoClassDefFoundError ignore) {

     //Do nothing

 }
```

If you have similar kind of issue, try this. It should work.

Comment: This is not what he is asking for. Please read the question carefully. Please see the image which is in the link